# KeyNotFoundException when trying to dervive from theme Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to write an app using Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio 2022 for target Android 12. I can compile and debug the app without any problems, but when I'm trying to archive it, I get a KeyNotFoundException without any other information.
I found out, that my theme is responsible for this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
  </style>
</resources>`
```

When I use Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar here, I get the error when trying to archive. The error doesn't occur with the default parent (MainTheme.Base).

When debugging the app, the theme seems to work and the error only occurs when trying to archive the final app. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have tried to debug and release with this style and never met the error.

Comment: @LiyunZhang: Thanks, I re-checked it with an empty project and couldn't reproduce it either. But now I found the second source of the problem and was able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

After retrying with an empty project and not being able to reproduce it, I stumbled over some obsolete references to System.ComponentModel.Annotations and Newtonsoft.Json.
After removing them, I can now archive the app.

No idea why the problem only occured with these references AND Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar set as parent theme, but I'm glad it works now.

**Edit:** After being able to archive many times now, the error suddenly occured again, but this time could be resolved by restarting VS.
Seems like the error is just some kind of hickup.